# Issue with CAS login

Tags: jmeter

I am new to jmeter and trying to login in one of our client application which uses CAS system, but not able to succeed. I have also applied regular expression extractor for "lt", but not works.

each time it gives this error:

> ticket 'LT-9528-aTBBoBdZU23g6khtS9I0b5Lq3o2VUQ' not recognized

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using hard-coded login ticked (recorded one). You need to perform so-called correlation - the process of identifying dynamic parameters, extracting and re-using them.

See [How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Sites](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites) to get an idea regarding approaches.

Also it worth checking [Apache JMeter](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Apache+JMeter) page of Jasig wiki, it seems to contain some JMeter scripts which you can use as a reference.

Comment: No i have used regular expression extractor for jt, but before that i have two more parameters Service and Register and it contains time timestamp  , do i need to use correlation for timestamp and if yes how to do that

Comment: Timestamp can be generated using [__time()](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) function. Have you checked sample contributed tests from above [CASUM Wiki](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Apache+JMeter) prior to asking?

Comment: Thanks friend for your valuable suggetions i found probelm there was one more parameter "execution" which also need to be correlated after doing this it worked..